# How can i have the tray icon load for a Qt app when it is executed through task scheduler?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, pyinstaller, pyside, trayicon

i have an python app with qt designer ui, i used pyinstaller to turn the .py to an exe, the tray icon works when manually executed, however once i try to run it using task scheduler the app runs but i get no icon.
I have attached two images showing both cases

What happens when ran manually

[image]

What happens when ran by task scheduler

[image]

I used pyinstaller --log-level DEBUG -F -d imports -w sample.py to convert the .py to a .exe

samply.py before being changed to an .exe

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QIcon, QMenu, QSystemTrayIcon

from test import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        icon = QIcon("logo.png")
        menu = QMenu()
        menu = QMenu()
        hideAction = menu.addAction("Hide")
        hideAction.triggered.connect(self.hide)
        showAction = menu.addAction("Show")
        showAction.triggered.connect(self.show)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("logo.png"))
        self.tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
        self.tray.setIcon(icon)
        self.tray.setContextMenu(menu)
        self.tray.setToolTip("Restart Scheduler!")
        self.show()


def main():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MainWindow()
    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

the .ui file converted to a .py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created: Mon Feb 10 14:40:44 2020
#      by: pyside-uic 0.2.15 running on PySide 1.2.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(311, 317)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 311, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

Comment: @eyllanesc i added a code sample

Answer (score 0):

The relative paths of the resources such as the logo are with respect to the sample.py but when they are converted to .exe those are relative to the .exe so there are following options:

1. Copy the logos in the same executable folder.
2. Set as "data" using the --add-data command: `pyinstaller --log-level DEBUG -F -d imports --add-data="logo.png;." -w sample.py` and modifying sample.py to:

   ```py
   # ...
   def resource_path(relative_path):
       """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
       try:
           # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
           base_path = sys._MEIPASS
       except Exception:
           base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

       return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


   class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
       def __init__(self):    
           super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
           self.setupUi(self)    
           icon = QIcon(resource_path("logo.png"))

           menu = QMenu(self)
           hideAction = menu.addAction("Hide")
           hideAction.triggered.connect(self.hide)
           showAction = menu.addAction("Show")
           showAction.triggered.connect(self.show)
           self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(resource_path("logo.png")))
           self.tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
           self.tray.setIcon(icon)
           self.tray.setContextMenu(menu)
           self.tray.setToolTip("Restart Scheduler!")
           self.show()
   # ...
   ```
3. Create a .qrc, convert it to .py and import it into sample.py:

   **resource.qrc**

   ```
   <RCC>
       <qresource prefix="/">
           <file>logo.png</file>
       </qresource>
   </RCC>
   ```

   ```
   pyside-rcc resource.qrc -o resource_rc.py
   ```

   **sample.py**

   ```
   # ...
   import resource_rc
   # ...
   class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
       def __init__(self):    
           super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
           self.setupUi(self)    
           icon = QIcon(":/logo.png")

           menu = QMenu(self)
           hideAction = menu.addAction("Hide")
           hideAction.triggered.connect(self.hide)
           showAction = menu.addAction("Show")
           showAction.triggered.connect(self.show)
           self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/logo.png"))
           self.tray = QSystemTrayIcon()
           self.tray.setIcon(icon)
           self.tray.setContextMenu(menu)
           self.tray.setToolTip("Restart Scheduler!")
           self.show()
   # ...
   ```

Comment: i did put the logo in the dist folder with the exe and that works fine when i manually run it, but doesnt one its ran from task scheduler

Comment: @AltonGraham Try the third method, that always works

Comment: got it to work by hard coding the path for the logo, or setting the start in location when making the action for the scheduler, initially it was looking for the logo image in the path where the exe is but task scheduler does not execute from that location by default

Comment: @AltonGraham So that you do not have such problems, I recommend using the third method since it does not use local files but embeds the icon in the executable